# How does WikiLeaks(Julian Assange) get the US Embassy cables?

Tags: data-leakage, government

How does this guy get these cables? Are those cables routed through a single node, where this guy got it? If so, How it is possible? I mean, how that single point came under the control of Julian Assange? If not, then how did he get them? Didn't they encrypted?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Kugathasan, welcome to the site! We had to close this question, since it calls for speculation, and anyway its not really a helpful question, as per the [FAQ]. As phrased, it's not even a security question...

Comment: A good place to start building a good question related to this is [One Year After Collateral Murder Release, DOD’s Networks Are Still Glaring Security Problem | Emptywheel](http://emptywheel.firedoglake.com/2011/04/05/the-response-to-the-wikileaks-reveals-dod-remains-vulnerable/)

Comment: I do not see why anyone would vote this down.  It is a legitimate question of how what should have been one of the most secure networks in the world was penetrated and senistive information was released.

Comment: @chad I didn't downvote it, but I did vote to close, and I understand the concern that the question as asked reflects very little homework done, and we discourage argumentative and misleading questions that lead to a waste of time.  Google will quickly show lots of background on this as evidenced by the article I already noted.  But I'd welcome a good non-argumentative question on what is known about SIPRnet, and what lessons can be learned by the rest of us.  It could either be a new question, or a reworded one here that leads to it being reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The long answer is quite complicated, and up for legal discussion.

The short answer is: He (Wikileaks) asked for them, and someone sent them.

Comment: So, didn't he steal in the middle?

Comment: Not according to the information that's available.

Comment: "He (Wikileaks) asked for them, and someone sent them." Only in so much as he asked that if anyone had documents that any goverment would like to cover up send them.  I have never seen anything that said he asked for the specific documents or more specifically anything that made the US look bad.

Comment: Yeah @chad I agree, wikileaks is just an intermediary for the 'leak' and there is case-law where newspapers are allowed to do this sort of thing (in fact they are key players in the publishing of **this** material).

Answer (score 0):

These cables were made available to military Intel people in theory to support anti terror operations.  The commanders of the Intel units failed to properly monitor and catch that highly classified and <del>top</del> secret material was being down loaded enmass, and then removed from the secure facilities.  The files were at some point reportedly on Bit Torrent in an Unredacted format where wikileaks staff downloaded them.

Comment: The material was "secret", not "top secret": [One Year After Collateral Murder Release, DOD’s Networks Are Still Glaring Security Problem | Emptywheel](http://emptywheel.firedoglake.com/2011/04/05/the-response-to-the-wikileaks-reveals-dod-remains-vulnerable/)

Comment: Some of the material was Top Secret No FORN.  A majority of it was simply classified.  Along with various classification in between

Comment: @chad Here is another source: [wikileaks have no top secret material « Niqnaq](http://niqnaq.wordpress.com/2010/12/18/wikileaks-have-no-top-secret-material/).  Can you provide a source for the assertion that there was top secret info?  Including which document was so classified?

Comment: http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/06/leak/ - I remember seeing several redacted documents that were stamped SECRET NOFORN DUPLICATION PROHIBITED.  The document may not have been top secret but the material it contained was:  Names of covert operatives and foreign intel sources as well as locations and dates of covert meetings and operations.

Comment: The Niqnaq story refutes the Wired story on that point.  Without specific claims it is hard to go any further here.

Comment: Actually Niqnaq just says they are wrong.  But then lists SECRET NOFORN as one of the classifications that it has.

Comment: But you claimed "top secret" info, which is quite different, and an entirely different military network is used for it.

Comment: Very well i edited the answer hope that makes you happy.  Generally I think most of us consider anything the government considers secret and release endangers lives as top secret but since there is a classifcation of TOP SECRET I will aquiesse.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't mean to offend, and found your answer helpful. I was just really interested in this classification debate, which has happened elsewhere too, so I was looking for specifics.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Chad, nealmcb is entirely right.  There is a huge difference between secret and top secret.  SECRET is secret, not top secret.  These differences matter.  (It's not just a matter of "making someone happy"; it is about accuracy.)